# What is Swift 4.1.50?

Tags: swift4.1, xcode10

I'm playing around with the Xcode 10 beta, and I noticed while doing compile-time checks of the Swift version number that projects with the **Swift  Language Version** set to **Swift 4** in their Build Settings are reporting as **Swift 4.1.50** <sub>(betas 2, 3, and 4 do this; I didn't get a chance to test beta 1)</sub>. This strikes me as... bizarre, to say the least. The current AppStore version of Xcode, Xcode 9.4.1, reports its version as **Swift 4.1.2**.

So... **What happened to Swift 4.1.3 through 4.1.49?** Or is this a bug that I should file? Or is the 50 significant in some way?

---

You can test this yourself with my test file, [Swift Version Checker](https://github.com/BenLeggiero/Swift-Version-Checker/blob/master/main.swift)

---

[image: A screenshot of Xcode 10 beta 4 using the above-linked file to detect Swift 4.1.50]
[image: A screenshot of Terminal reproducing the bug using the <code>swift</code> command]

Comment: Looks like a bug, compare https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51307937/swift-version-build-configuration for a similar observation.

Comment: Filed [SR-8323](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-8323)

Comment: It's a pseudo version, just like Swift 3.2, 3.3 and 3.4. 4.1.50 is the language version of a Swift 4.2 compiler running in Swift 4 compatibility mode. See https://forums.swift.org/t/se-0212-compiler-version-directive/12267/7

Comment: Yes, I know that, but why `50`? Why not `3`?

Comment: Jordan Rose has now provided the rationale [in the comments of the bug report you filed](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-8323?focusedCommentId=38063&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-38063) :) Feel free to write a self-answer, or I can write an answer if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Jordan Rose on the Swift bug tracker:

> This is the least bad answer we could come up with, given that we may still release more 4.1.x versions if there's, say, a bad security vulnerability in one of them. (This has happened before.) We needed a version number that was greater than any existing 4.1 version, but still less than 4.2.
>
> We did consider other ideas, but this is the one we went with for maximum compatibility. We at least won't have this problem in the future thanks to SE-0212.

So, what I take from this is that there might still have to be an actual 4.1 release sometime in the future, but that would just be a security patch atop 4.1.2, so the logical number for that would be 4.1.3. Meanwhile, the pseudo-4.1 Swift that the Swift 4.2 compiler can digest needs its own number that also reflects it's a dialect of 4.1, and their conclusion was 4.1.50, which is safely far enough away from 4.1.2 to allow for as many security patches as they want.